# How to return the mean value of the corresponding column in a pandas DataFrame using fillna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

How to return the mean value of the corresponding column in a pandas DataFrame using fillna. Basically, if I have column total_bill and data_usage for example, I want to fill all the NaN in total_bill column with the mean value of all entries in total_bill column. In a like manner, fill all the NaN in data_usage column with the mean value of all entries in data_usage column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean by:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(df[col].mean())
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! I was thinking more in terms of a single line of code (if possible, like a function or lambda fx). So, I was not very flexible in my thinking to realize that I could just redefine the columns that way. Even though that will mean that if I have 10 columns, I will have to redefine all if they all have NaN. Thanks again.

Comment: @aanifowose111 Edited my answer now should be better

Comment: Thanks!! It works!!! Except that it first threw an error for indentation for line 2.

Comment: Yeah, the indentation makes all the difference.